# Updating records of different type, but with same base class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, .net-4.0

I'm trying to update records of different type, but all of these are based of the same base type, `BaseEntity` (which has `OwnerId` among its members)

This is done so I can transfer ownership of records of all tables from one user to another.

Here's what I have to far:

```
public ActionResult TransferOwnership(int sourceUserId, int targetUserId)
{
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    var tables = metadata.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace).Where(x => x.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType).ToList();

    foreach (var table in tables)
    {
        var tableName = table.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(table);
        List<BaseEntity> entities = Context.Database.SqlQuery<BaseEntity>($"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE OwnerId = {sourceUserId}").ToList();

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            entity.OwnerId = targetUserId;
            Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; //this fails
        }

        if (entities.Count > 0)
            Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

On the line where I set the entity's state, I get an error saying the type `BaseEntity` is not tracked by the context.

I could use the table name to cast the object to its real type, but then I'd need to do something like:

```
Context.MyTable1.Attach(entity);
```

But that looses its generic appeal; I'd have to address all table explicitly.

I remember in older version of EF, you could do something like `Context.ChangeTracker.Attach(entity)` but that seems to be gone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TransferOwnership(int sourceUserId, int targetUserId)
{
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    var tables = metadata.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace).Where(x => x.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType).ToList();
    //some entities were cast to their proxy types which were unconvertable with Convert.ChangeType...
    Context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    foreach (var table in tables)
    {
        var tableName = table.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(table);
        var type = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseEntity)).GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == tableName.ToString());

        List<object> entities = await Context.Database.SqlQuery(type, $"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE OwnerId = {sourceUserId}").ToListAsync();

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var e = entity as BaseEntity;
            e.OwnerId = targetUserId;
            Context.Set(type).Attach(Convert.ChangeType(e, type));
            Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        if (entities.Count > 0)
            Context.SaveDirect();
    }


    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In EF Core DbContext has Attach Method, but in EF DbSet has Attach(Object entity) method. You should use DbSet to add change tracking mechanism to your generic entity.

source: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.attach?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Update:

You can try this: `context.Set(entity.GetType()).Attach(entity)`